# Not able to setvalue to a form field in webdriverio Cucumber framework

Tags: node.js, cucumber, webdriver-io

I am very new to webdriver io and cucumber framework.Tried my first test with login screen of an application. I am able to invoke the browser and website is loaded.But I when try to setvalue for the login field , it throws the following error and aborts

**"Error in "Performing a login: Login with the default user: When I login with the default user"
browser.$(...).setValue is not a function"**

I tried to install sync package and set sync to true in config file.I could not get it to work . Please help !

Here is my config file

exports.config = {

```
//
// ====================
// Runner Configuration
// ====================
//
// WebdriverIO allows it to run your tests in arbitrary locations (e.g. locally or
// on a remote machine).
runner: 'local',
//
path: '/wd/hub',

specs: [
    './features/*.feature'
],
// Patterns to exclude.
exclude: [
    // 'path/to/excluded/files'
],
//

maxInstances: 10,

capabilities: [{

    // maxInstances can get overwritten per capability. So if you have an in-house Selenium
    // grid with only 5 firefox instances available you can make sure that not more than
    // 5 instances get started at a time.
    maxInstances: 5,
    //
    browserName: 'firefox',
    // If outputDir is provided WebdriverIO can capture driver session logs
    // it is possible to configure which logTypes to include/exclude.
    // excludeDriverLogs: ['*'], // pass '*' to exclude all driver session logs
    // excludeDriverLogs: ['bugreport', 'server'],
}],

logLevel: 'info',
sync:true,
bail: 0,

baseUrl: '********************',
//
// Default timeout for all waitFor* commands.
waitforTimeout: 10000,
//
// Default timeout in milliseconds for request
// if browser driver or grid doesn't send response
connectionRetryTimeout: 90000,
//
// Default request retries count
connectionRetryCount: 3,

services: ['selenium-standalone'],


framework: 'cucumber', 


cucumberOpts: {
    requireModule: ['@babel/register'],// <string[]> ("extension:module") require files with the given EXTENSION after requiring MODULE (repeatable)
    require: ['./step-definitions/*.js'],       // <string[]> (file/dir) require files before executing features

    backtrace: false,   // <boolean> show full backtrace for errors
    dryRun: false,      // <boolean> invoke formatters without executing steps
    //compiler: ['js:babel-core/register'],
    failFast: false,    // <boolean> abort the run on first failure
    format: ['pretty'], // <string[]> (type[:path]) specify the output format, optionally supply PATH to redirect formatter output (repeatable)
    snippets: true,     // <boolean> hide step definition snippets for pending steps
    source: true,       // <boolean> hide source uris
    profile: [],        // <string[]> (name) specify the profile to use
    strict: false,      // <boolean> fail if there are any undefined or pending steps
    tagExpression: '',  // <string> (expression) only execute the features or scenarios with tags matching the expression
    timeout: 60000,     // <number> timeout for step definitions
    ignoreUndefinedDefinitions: false, // <boolean> Enable this config to treat undefined definitions as warnings.
},
```

Comment: It would be helpful to add a tag for the language you are using with Cucumber. This will make it more likely to get a response. This looks like javascript? I also would suggest posting your actual code. `setValue is not a function` indicates that the issue you are having is you're perhaps using the function incorrectly or have mis-spelled something. Seeing the code would help someone diagnose it.

Comment: ya i am using node.js, webdriverio with cuucmber framework.

Comment: It looks much better, and you're getting responses! You can also improve your chance of getting an answer with tags. In this case I suggest adding the Node tag.

Answer (score 0):

Try to execute this simple test case instead:

```
describe("webdriver.io page", () => {
it("should have the right title", () => {
    browser.url('https://www.google.com');
    browser.maximizeWindow();
    $('input[name="q"]').setValue('some text');
    });
});
```

And can you post your test case example please?

Cucumber example:

```
When('user enters valid username', () => {
  loginPage.emailAddress.addValue('some text');
});
```

Where **loginPage** is a PageObject that contain **emailAddress** as an element.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack-overflow. The more relevant details you give in your question, the sooner you get your answer.

The issue could be any of the below three as far as I know.

1) setValue is not working on your element because you don't have a proper element selected. You can try to improve your selector/locator.

2) you can try to click in the text area and try to use [keys](https://webdriver.io/docs/api/browser/keys.html) api.

3) You dont need [path](https://webdriver.io/docs/options.html#path) property set to that value. you can leave it to default '/'.

Reference: Sample [repo](https://github.com/spnraju/demo-webdriverio-cucumberjs/blob/master/features/step-definitions/home-page.steps.js) on GitHub

Answer (score 0):

I chose async mode for running commands when adding dependencies while creating config.js .I deleted the workspace and repeated all steps .But this time changed  it to sync mode for running commands and wrote the same code again.everything is working. Thanks all for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Sometime input field may have special formatting.  Like Input text for Phone Number, or SSN or Date of Birth and dev set the maskChar = " ".  This may work fine manually but creates problem when you use the setValue();

So the quick and easy solution to that is :

```
const input = await $(selector);
await input.setValue(['Home', 'my Text']);
```

Replace the 'my Text' with your variable or const.  Now, when WDIO execute this line, It will first clear the text (as part of setValue) and then it will press the 'Home' key followed by your text.